# Get info from URL in a Page Tab

Tags: facebook, authentication, tabs

Trying to work out Authorization within a page tab app. I direct user to the auth dialog which redirects them back to my page tab with "&code=XXXXXXX..." in the url.

However, `$code = $_REQUEST["code"];`, which always worked on a canvas app, isn't working for me in the page tab app. How do I access my code to proceed with authorization?

Or... Am I unable to access info in the url with PHP?

Apologies if this is a repeat, but in searching all I've found were questions asking how to get the page url for the sake of redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a querystring, try `$_GET["code"]` or you could try parsing `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`

Comment: I've tried $_GET to no avail, it seems to only be able to access the url within the iframe (i.e. mydomain.com/facebookapp/) and not the page url (http://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGE_NAME/PAGE_ID?sk=.....)

I'll try $_SERVER thanks.

Comment: So the querystring you're trying to access is within the parent doc?

Comment: Correct. And it seems `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` is also looking at my domain, not the parent doc. Not surprised. Feeling like I may have to use javascript?

If that's that case... get it with javascript and save it as a cookie that I can then access with PHP?

Comment: Would so love to be able to do it all with PHP though. Won't safari not allow cookies to be set from within an iframe?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do that if your iframe is located on a different domain than the main site.  Cross-site scripting won't work in any browser.  Is it possible to have the iframe generated with the querystring passed directly to it instead?

Comment: Maybe... Facebook let's you specify an "app_data" parameter to the iframe in a link to a page. So if I have the auth dialog redirect to a page on my server that can read the code via $_GET, I can then redirect the user back to my page on facebook with the code passed in the app_data. That's just so many redirect for the poor user to login.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to get `code` passed to URL of your Facebook Page tab this way since only parameter that passed to your Page tab via URL is `app_data`.

You should use one of:

- URL that reside in under your Page Canvas URL to finish auth flow and then redirect user back to Page Tab
- Using JS-SDK `FB.login` method to authorize user.